# jQuery .ajax call returning undefined or null in the success function call

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery ajax call:

```
executeAllAjaxCalls:function() {
    if (WALMART.jQuery.ajaxCalls.length) {
        var dataPassed = "ajaxCalls="+WALMART.jQuery.ajaxCalls;        

        WALMART.jQuery.ajax({   
            url: WALMART.jQuery.ajaxFrameworkUrl                     
            , data: dataPassed
            , dataType: WALMART.jQuery.jsonResponseType   
            , type: 'POST'   
            , success: WALMART.jQuery.AjaxObject_Consolidated.processConsolidatedData
        });
    }       
}
```

The data coming back in the function call upon success is undefined.

Here is the function called upon success of the ajax call:

```
processConsolidatedData:function(result) {
    alert("1234"+result);
    var responseData = eval('(' + result.responseText + ')');
    if (typeof responseData !== '') {
        for (resp in responseData) {
                ALMART.jQuery(document).ready(responseData[resp].CallbackFunction);             
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the response null or undefined when the struts action at the backend c:out a valid JSON object.  Any tips or pointers appreciated as I am very new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your code...

```
    for (resp in responseData) {
            ALMART.jQuery(document).ready(responseData[resp].CallbackFunction);             
    }
```

I think you ment:

```
    for (resp in responseData) {
            WALMART.jQuery(document).ready(responseData[resp].CallbackFunction);             
    }
```

I would also use jQuery.parseJSON instead of 'eval', unless necessary.